# How i can save apify actor output to s3 or google bucket

Tags: apify

I have created the apify actor it save the output in apify cloud but i want to save the output in my s3 account or the google bucket.
thanks for any help to do this

Comment: What have you tried to do this so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a webhook/serverless function on `gcp/aws` and set the endpoint into apify task webhooks
[image]

The incoming webhook body will look like

```
{
  "userId": {{userId}},
  "createdAt": {{createdAt}},
  "eventType": {{eventType}},
  "eventData": {{eventData}},
  "resource": {{resource}}
}
```

where resource will be like below when `SUCCESS`

```
{
  "id": {{id}},
  "actId": {{actId}},
  "userId": {{userId}},
  "startedAt": "2020-03-29T04:12:07.434Z",
  "finishedAt": "2020-03-29T04:12:13.415Z",
  "status": "SUCCEEDED",
  "meta": {
    "origin": "DEVELOPMENT",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36"
  },
  "stats": {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  },
  "options": {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  },
  "buildId": {{buildId}},
  "exitCode": 0,
  "defaultKeyValueStoreId": {{defaultKeyValueStoreId}},
  "defaultDatasetId": {{defaultDatasetId}},
  "defaultRequestQueueId": {{defaultRequestQueueId}},
  "buildNumber": "0.0.9",
  "containerUrl": {{containerUrl}}
}
```

Then you can download/save-to-bucket-or-s3 your dataset with the URL: `https://api.apify.com/v2/datasets/{{defaultDatasetId}}/items`
programmatically

I hope this helps!